# Namespacing views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was referred to [Juggling Larger Laravel Applications](http://ryantablada.com/post/juggling-larger-laravel-applications) and I'm havihng trouble getting

```
View::addNamespace('Marketing', __DIR__.'/../Views')
```

to work in one of my sub-app directories where the **views** are located at */var/www/myapp.com/app/MyApp/Marketing/Views*

Placing this code in my */var/www/myapp.com/app/MyApp/Marketing/Providers/MarketingServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Marketing\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class MarketingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {

    }

    public function boot()
    {
        require_once(__DIR__.'/../routes.php');
        View::addNamespace('Marketing', __DIR__.'/../Views');
    }
}
```

and referencing it in my routes file like

```
Route::group(array('domain' => array('www.myapp.dev')), function()
{
    return View::make('Marketing::index');
});
```

results in **No hint path defined for [Marketing].**

I've also added

```
MyApp\Marketing\Providers\MarketingServiceProvider
```

to the provider's config array.

Lastly, I'm using psr-0 in composer

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "app/"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I'm stupid... the problem wasn't what I thought it was…

```
Route::group(array('domain' => array('www.myapp.dev')), function()
{
    return View::make('Marketing::index');
});
```

Changing my route to that above fixes everything. I accidentally had www.myapp.dev in an additional array which was causing all of the unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Im confused too... Whats wrong with:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => array('www.myapp.dev')), function()
{
    return View::make('marketing.index');
});
```

and storing your marketing index view as: `app/views/marketing/index.blade.php`?

Comment: Nothing. `domain` was set to a string (i.e 'www.myapp.dev'), not an array which was causing all my problems.

Answer (score -2):

Why on earth would you try to namespace a view? Just put them in a folder called "marketing"...

Comment: I have _MyApp/Marketing/Views_, _MyApp/API/Views_, and _MyApp/Admin/Views_. I have an **index.blade.php** in each. How would Laravel know which view I was calling without namespacing it?

Comment: Your view-files are not PHP classes, so therefore do not get namespaced. Your controllers specify which view to load, using folders to pick that out. If "marking", "admin" and "api" folders are not clear enough then you are doing something truly bizarre.

Comment: It doesn't feel bizarre :) I'm referring to _Resource Namespace_ which is achieved via `View::addNamespace()`. Found my problem and it was not related to what I was chasing.

Comment: I had to do the same thing, I had to logically split my views along with the classes I needed for models and controllers. Folders is nice but sometimes the application needs a different structure.

Comment: Perhaps there's a situation in which you want to modularize your code...